# Call Groovy Closure from Java Class - Will it Compile?

Tags: java, groovy, compilation

I have some legacy Java code inside which I'd like to call a groovy Closure.

Is this something that the Java / Groovy cross-compiler will be able to handle?  I suspect it compiles Java first, but does it do another pass over the Groovy bytecode to resolve all the java references.

Or do I need to compile the class with closure first into a jar, so that I can access it from Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this for mixing Java and Groovy : 
[Mixed Java and Groovy Applications](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Mixed+Java+and+Groovy+Applications)

> This example looks at the issues
>   surrounding a mixed Java/Groovy
>   application. This issue only arises
>   when there is mutual dependencies
>   between your mixed language source
>   files. So, if part of your system is
>   pure Java for instance, you won't have
>   this problem. You would just compile
>   that part of your system first and
>   reference the resulting class/jar
>   file(s) from the part of your system
>   that was written in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Without having to do anything in particular, I just got a simple version of this to work by following the advice from SjB's article and creating an interface in Java, which the groovy class then implements.

In java:

```
interface decorator {
    public String decorate(String in) ;
}
```

And then implementing in Groovy:

```
class GroovyDecorator implements decorator {
    public String decorate(String in) {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Then using this in Java like:

```
...
public void javaFunc(someObject someStuff, decorator d) {
    // do some stuff
    d.decorate("input string");
}
```

And calling from groovy:

```
GroovyDecorator gd = new GroovyDecorator() ;
javaFunc(someStuff, gd) ;
```

This worked fine without having to do any special compilation, although I am working in an established groovy environment that may have some special configuration I'm not aware of.

Note that the auto recompilation of .groovy files did not work. If I changed GroovyDecorator, I had to restart grails, which makes implementing stuff like this much less useful.